# Pass URL parameters from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I have an iframe hosted on my site which is provided by a third party service. I can't manipulate the source code of the iframe and this results in users being able to navigate through the frame whilst the parent URL remains the same. For example

`mysite.co.uk/`

This presents an issue in regards to tracking and further, post session navigation etc.

Is it possible to listen for events of the hosted iframe and then pass in URL parameters? For example, a user clicks on a listing within an iframe and there URL is appended

```
mysite.co.uk/listings?listing1
mysite.co.uk/listings?listing2
mysite.co.uk/listings?listing3
```

My research suggests JaveScript `window.` & `location.` but I'm struggling with these suggestions given that I can't amend the code of the iframe.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to do this with a same-domain iFrame, unless you can get the third party to make changes on their end to enable CORS.

Comment: Thanks for this - yes, you're correct. I had to approach the 3rd party and they have helped.